# ElasticSearch with Java Spring Or Spring Boot/Spring Data Proper Example

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data

I am new To Elastic Search and have gone through their documents where they implemented it using Rest api .But I need to integrate Spring Data or Spring Boot with Elastic Search.But I am not finding proper example.On their site, they have given documentation using Java but not so Clear.So can anyone give proper link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they wrote a lot of documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/).

Might not be up to date for elasticsearch 2.x though.

A full example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/elasticsearch

Comment: Yes I checked the documentation but I want to check out some sample code

Comment: I Updated the answer